# What's the better way to use getResources() many time in Android

Tags: android, android-resources

Im my app, i use alot of `getResources()` like that

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceid, opts);
```

i can use Resources res = getResources() as Global variable and use

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resourceid, opts);
```

So, my question is: What's the better way to avoid memory leak?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do it this way on occasion which I think can be fine but you just have to watch it. In your situation, I'm not sure that its worth creating a `Global` variable when nothing is changing. I will do it for a function to get a certain resource depending on `context` or some other variable. But here, I don't see how

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resourceid, opts);
```

is any better than

```
BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, resourceid, opts);
```

It seems that you are adding one extra unnecessary step

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't try to micro optimize this too much, just use common practices about creating less garbage where possible.  By this, I mean avoid decoding something, and letting it go out of scope and decoding it again.

Really, unless you keep decoding huge images or something like that, I don't see any problems.